# Jquery UI Accordion: automatic close a section

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery ui widget accordion. I wanted to know if there is a way to close a section automatically after a certain number of seconds.

You can write some sample code?

Thanks in advance
Danilo

Comment: You can check it here on the ui API
http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be something like that:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true,
        activate: function( event, ui ) {
            setTimeout(function() {     
                $('#accordion').accordion('activate', false );
            },5000);
        }
    });
  });
```

You'll have to adjust to your specific case, [try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5tqN/)

Comment: Thanks Renan Malke Stigliani. It was just what I needed!! :D

Answer (score 0):

The SO community usually looks down upon "Write the code for me" questions.  I will give you a hint, but in the future, please try something yourself before asking here.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.accordion').accordion('activate', false );
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Hi Steve.

I meant if you could write me an example because I have now started to study jquery and jquery ui. I did not want to offend anyone!

I tried to create it alone, but I did not succeed. That's why I asked for help.